# PHP image gallery from given folders

Tags: php, html

I am using the following code to output folders inside a certain directory:

```
$path = 'uploads/eventos/';
$results = scandir($path);

foreach ($results as $result) {
    if ($result === '.' or $result === '..') continue;

    if (is_dir($path . '/' . $result)) {
        echo $result."<br />";
    }
}
```

Then I use this to get files (images), inside each of the directories found:

```
$dirname = "uploads/eventos/directory1/";
$images = glob($dirname.'*.{jpg,jpeg,png,JPG,JPEG,PNG}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

This works. But my idea is being able to generate something similar to an image gallery. Where I first get a list of "links" to the folders, then when I click, open in the same page but showing the images inside.

Please, could someone point me to information? I need a simple solution, just for learning, not a complex image gallery. :)

Thank you!!

---- EDIT ---- Clear my explanation!

I have this folder structure (for example):

```
folder1/
       image1.jpg
       image2.jpg ...
folder2/
       image1.jpg
       image2.jpg 
       image3.jpg ...
```

I'd like to be able to output:

List:

```
<a href="folder1">folder1</a>
<a href="folder2">folder2</a>
```

And I would like to be able to click those links to open in the same page, a gallery such as (for example):

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="image1.jpg" /></td>
        <td><img src="image1.jpg" /></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
```

I think it is clearer now! :)

Comment: @FerozAkbar I think I cleared it. What I want I know it may be achieved with sql, but I am trying to do it just with files and folders, I think it may be possible. Regards

Answer (score 0):

this series will help you get this and understand it as well :)

https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D6-1c2lG7j0U&ei=gmSHU_X_GO-w7Ab8tYHQBQ&usg=AFQjCNGfXrWUNAG_gs-8Gn32cHuwfc8wnQ&sig2=lKCQRt5a_vEOgWdonBJH5w

code will be something like grabing all files/directories excluding "." and ".." thn in foreach loop you can ecoo

```
echo "<a href="'.$somepath.'/'.$file">$file</a>";
```

then on other page or same page $_GET forder naem and opendir that folder scan for non directories and deal with pics now :)

Comment: Thank you, I will watch and try to implement! Then accept answer ;)